# facebook javascript api does not return anything

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to setup Facebook api check IF user is logged in Facebook and liked my page, so I show specific content for him on my webpage.

Currently I have:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{my-appID}',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log('Logged in.');
      }
      else {
        FB.login();
      }
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));  
</script>
```

thought this javascript is totally silent, no errors, no console messages, nothing. Other js works just fine on same page. If I put this to head then it gives no FB defined, but on bottom of the page, I get no error, no response, nothing... As far as I understand, init should launch asap and check if the user is logged in Facebook, right ?

Comment: what for do you need to know if the user liked your page?

Comment: So I can show him content that is for Facebook people only

Comment: ok, because that is not allowed. you must read the platform policy. you can´t reward users in any way or gate content behind a like. like gating is not allowed since a very long time now.

Comment: about the issue at hand, see my anwer

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FB.login` on user interaction (mouse event), you can´t use it in an asynchronous callback function. Browsers will block the popup.

Example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/